# How to get UniqueViolationException instead of org.postgresql.util.PSQLException(or DataIntegrityViolationException)?

Tags: postgresql, exception, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've got Spring Boot (4), using Postgres(9.4) and JPA Data. I have a data table with a unique constraint:

```
 CREATE TABLE sys
(
  sys_id serial NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT sys_pk PRIMARY KEY (sys_id),
  CONSTRAINT sys_name_unique UNIQUE (name)
)
```

And I'm trying to write a code in my controller to save a new sys, but when I test saving a non-unique name, I can't catch a UniqueValiationException. Instead, I've got a postgrs error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sys_name_unique"
  Key(name)=(namea) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
    etc

I saw that the exception was called DataIntegrityViolationException. When I catch it, it gets caught. But shouldn't it be a UniqueViolationException instead?

My Sys entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys") 
public class Sys implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sys_id")
    private Integer sysId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Sys() {
    }
 //getters and setter below
```

ModelException.java:

```
public class ModelException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7808396136535585717L;

    private final String field;

    public ModelException(String field, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

UniqueViolationException.java:
    public class UniqueViolationException extends ModelException {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2105504304295367749L;


    public UniqueViolationException(String field, String message) {
        super(field, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're asking. What are those two exceptions? And how do you except these to be thrown exactly?

Comment: I have the unique constraint in my database. When I try to insert a new non-unique value into the database (via my application), I should get an exception, right? It would make sense to get UniqueViolationException, but I don't receive that. Instead, this is in my console: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sys_name_unique" Key(name)=(namea) already exists. at etc

Comment: So, I decided to catch that:
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {logger.error("Exception{}", ex.toString());}
and this is what I get is this scenario:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: Or should I expect DataIntegrityViolationException? It's my first time trying to properly catch exceptions in spring boot

Answer (score 4):

You can implement this by catching the PSQLException and then looking at its error code.

```
catch (PSQLException e) {
    /*
     * "23505" is the state that indicates Unique Constraint Violation
     * https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/errcodes-appendix.html
     */
    if ("23505".equals(e.getSQLState())) {
        ServerErrorMessage postgresError = e.getServerErrorMessage();
        if (postgresError != null) {
            String constraint = postgresError.getConstraint();
            if ("yourTable_pkey".equalsIgnoreCase(constraint)) {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the headup to using getSQLState() to match error codes. The current PosgreSQL URL is still relevant: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html